# vb.net combobox values in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

Recently i created a pos but i want to use a combobox rather than a radio button to select a tax option but how can i choose the tax i want and do the mathematics:
here is my code of radio button , i want to do it but with combobox

```
Dim SellPrice as Double
Dim Tax as Double
Dim FinalPrice 


if radiobutton1=checked=true than
 Final price *=Sellprice *0.18
 else if radiobutton2=checked=true than
Final price *=Sellprice *0.5
end if
```

i want to do the same but to use combobox rather than radiobutton

Comment: `If cbo.SelectedIndex = 0 Then ... Else ... End if`

Comment: should i write this on the combobox sub or the insert product sub ?

Comment: If you only have 2 radio buttons then you don't need the `ElseIf` and can just use `Else`, providing that you ensure one of them always starts selected.. Similarly, if you only provide two ComboBox options with no empty value then you can still just use `Else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form load :

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("0.18")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("0.5")
       'Add other values if you wan
End sub
```

in your validation button :

```
 Private Sub BtnValidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnValidate.Click

        Dim SellPrice As Double
        Dim Tax As Double
        Dim FinalPrice
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            Tax = Convert.ToDouble(ComboBox1.Text)
            FinalPrice *= SellPrice * Tax
        End If
    End Sub
```